# Excel: How to prevent "Refresh All" from activating "Worksheet_Change" VBA trigger

Tags: excel, vba, excelquery

I have a VBA trigger listening for user changes in the sheet. It is also a sheet that Queries a SQL Database and prints the information. When the user clicks "Refresh All", it also triggers the "Worksheet_Change" Sub.

How can I prevent the Worksheet_Change sub from activating on "Refresh All", or check how recently the Query was run (to skip the logic in the sub after it's called).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Jump to end to return functionality if an error occurs
    On Error GoTo haveError
    
    ' Prevent infinite loop of self updates
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim change_range, change_cell As Range
    Dim notActive As Boolean
    Dim cell_count As Integer
    Dim changed_cell_array As Variant
    Set change_range = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:G"))
    cell_count = 0
    
    ReDim changed_cell_array(3, 0)
    
    If change_range Is Nothing Then
        ' Cell update was not in range
    
    Else
        ' Loop through all cells in update trigger
        For Each change_cell In change_range.Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(change_cell) Then ' Ignore the empty cells
                ' Debug.Print "Target ID = " & CStr(Cells(change_cell.Row, 1).Value) & vbTab & vbTab & "Cell Value = " & CStr(change_cell.Value)
                cell_count = cell_count + 1
                
                ReDim Preserve changed_cell_array(3, cell_count)
                
                changed_cell_array(0, cell_count) = Cells(change_cell.Row, 1).Value
                changed_cell_array(1, cell_count) = change_cell.Value
                changed_cell_array(2, cell_count) = change_cell.Row
                changed_cell_array(3, cell_count) = change_cell.Column
                
            End If
    
        Next change_cell
    End If
    
    Debug.Print CStr(cell_count) & " cells changed"
    
    RunPython "import testing2; testing2.pass_array(" & CStr(cell_count) & ")"
    
haveError:
    
    ' Return excel to its normal state
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe check to see if `Target` is a specific range corresponding to the query table or whatever is getting updated on that sheet?  Something you can use to exit the event handler without taking further action....

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Tim.
What I'm trying to do, is listen if the user has edited the Database query, and then pass that change back to the SQL database as an update. So I need to allow the user to edit the same range as the Query.

Comment: Agreed but are they editing one or a few cells at a time, and what is `Target.Address` and how does it differ when the event is triggered by a "Refresh All" ?

Comment: For example:  `Debug.Print Target.Address = Me.ListObjects("TableResult").Range.Address` was True when I tested refreshing a query table on a worksheet.

Comment: Would this still allow the script to run when a user edits data within that table? Because that is my goal. I would like to listen for user edits on the table, while ignoring the Query refreshes to the table.

Comment: It would only exit if the user edits the whole table at once, which seems unlikely to happen.   Is the data in a Table/ListObject?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Tim! After some light testing this seems to be working well for me. If you'd like, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe check to see if `Target` is a specific range corresponding to the query table or whatever is getting updated on that sheet?

Something you can use to exit the event handler without taking further action.

For example a test like this might exit the event handler if a entire Table/ListObject is updated:

```
If Target.Address = Me.ListObjects("TableResult").Range.Address Then Exit Sub
```